# Bandwidth Measurements during offloading from mobile device to cloud

Tags: java, android, performance, cloud

I am creating a framework by using computation offloading approach to minimize the energy consumption in Mobile Device. I offloaded an application to cloud side to do a computation service. I have some conditions that need predicted values of some parameters before doing the task of offloading. One of the main parameters is the bandwidth for each offloaded task that should be known before offloading process. I used "Ping technique" to predict the average bandwidth for uploading/downloading the data packets in sending/receiving from/to server but that did not give an optimal solution to save energy during offloading process.

Is there any thought or idea about the optimal solution for this issue that could be useful in cellular/wireless networking?